# material-ui overlay div behind Drawer Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material-ui in a React app. I'm using the side menu "Drawer" component but cannot figure out how to include the semi-transparent background overlay behind the open menu.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docked example presents the Drawer without the backdrop.

The undocked example presents the Drawer with a semi-transparent backdrop that hides the drawer when clicked.

The difference lies with the `docked` property.  If true, the Drawer will be docked and there will be no backdrop.  If false, the backdrop will be present.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class DrawerUndockedExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton
          label="Open Drawer"
          onClick={this.handleToggle}
        />
        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          width={200}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Review the [Drawer demos and API docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer) for more info.

**Note:** For future readers, this concerns material-ui v0.x.  The latest version of [Drawer](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/drawers) in version 1.0.0-beta24 has been drastically improved and is more compliant with the published [Material Design standards](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Comment: `docked` doesn't seem to be a prop on Drawer these days. Can't seem to find an equivalent. You aware of a current solution?

Comment: @Levitikon I think the Temporary Drawer is the current solution: https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#temporary-drawer

Answer (score 2):

I've found this to work for me, I hope it helps.
remove `variant="persistent"`